# How to host web map app on ArcGIS.com?

Tags: arcgis-server, web-mapping, web-service, arcgis-online

I have created a web map app on [**arcgis.com**](http://arcgis.com).

I have installed ArcGIS 10.2 for Server, and created a services and published it on [**arcgis.com**](http://arcgis.com), but it is local server.

I want to any one opening my web map app from any other PC not my PC

**[Here](https://nce.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=6bcaf343ff8c4605b40b770baf87c4f7)** is my web map app.

Comment: If you have an ArcGIS.com account, why not publish the services to ArcGIS.com as opposed to your own server? This will get around any issues with having to expose your ArcGIS Server to the internet.  Let me know if this is what you want and I can help more in a more detailed answer

Answer (score 2):

Then you should make your PC available to everyone. This can be achieved in various ways, but you essentially need to make your ArcGIS Server public and this involves making changes in firewall of your organization and network settings often including DNS.

You could probably talk with someone if your company already has a dedicated server - in this case you could publish your services there (and if no ArcGIS Server was installed there - install it there first). I seriously doubt your security policy will allow make your personal machine available to public via the Internet, so you should look for other options.

Comment: i have installed arcgis server 10.2 with web adaptor and i configured web adaptor successfully and gived me a url " http://localhost/mywebmap/rest/services", i have an antivirus too on my pc, i dont know if this make a problem with my firewall or not, i just want to a guideline how to make a publish my web map app to any one on arcgis.com server, i have not organization DNS, i just make my web map public on arcgis.com server.

Comment: ArcGIS.com does have access to your PC and since you are viewing the web application you've published from your PC, you also able to access your GIS services. Other users won't, because they don't have access to your PC. If you want to turn your desktop machine into a public facing server, you need to consult your OS documentation on further guidelines.

Comment: i have win7 ultimate sp1 with the latest updates, i have too installed eset nod 32 smart security, windows firewall has managed by nod32 smart security and it turned off,firewall using nod32 instead of windows firewall, in "arcgisserver,inetpub" folders, i turned to fullpermission, if any other guideline you want, please alert me.

Comment: i think "Remote Desktop Connection", one the features to make my pc public, if not i mistake.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not all that easy as it may seem. You will need to do some work and you need to learn how to set up a public facing server, there isn't any other "quick" way to expose your GIS services to the outside world.

Comment: OK, can you post any external link that i will learning how to set up a public facing server.

Comment: There are tons of resources available, just search. http://superuser.com/questions/344745/how-do-i-run-a-local-web-facing-server for instance