# How to set up a public facing server?

Tags: arcgis-server, web-mapping, web-service, arcgis-online

Based on this post [How to host web map app on ArcGIS.com?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82420/how-to-host-web-map-app-on-arcgis-com)

I have installed ArcGIS server 10.2 for .NET with web adapter, on Win7 SP1 ultimate. I just followed the guideline, how to set up my web map as public facing server, and I have published services successfully.  Then I registered in arcgis.com as a new user for free. Then I have created a new organization and group, and finally I added a new item as web map application, but my challenge is how to make my web map app public for anyone?

So can anyone guide me how to solving it, @Alex Tereshenkov, talking about set up a public facing server, but I can't understand what he means!

OK, here is more information:

My IP 10.10.1.103

subset mask: 255.255.255.0

I put my IP address like this "10.10.1.103/arcgis/rest, but it is not responding, in Firefox says the connection has timed out, also in Internet Explorer,

I have installed IIS for ArcGIS server

default gateway: 10.1.1.254

Comment: your computer (or server) needs accessed by other computers then it needs to be moved from the local network to the internet or at least create a portal through a firewall to that PC/Server. This no a GIS question but a http://serverfault.com/ question.

Comment: Ok, lets start with basic troubleshooting. You have AGS installed as well as the Web-Adaptor. We need to see what your IP Address looks like, go to the command line (run option on Start Menu) and do IPCONFIG /all. Then update your question with the information under your Ethernet adapter line. From there we can see if you can access the http://ipaddress/arcgis/rest URLs to show you have connectivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a [web server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server).

Since you're using Windows you may be interested in [IIS (Internet Information Services)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services). It's a web server and can be run from any machine. You'll essentially end up with a folder on your machine that is accessible to those outside. You would then place all of the information you want the public to access in this folder, including your published maps and associated data.

In order to continuously host from the server the machine will always need to be on and connected to the internet, therefore most people would choose a dedicated machine for this task.

Comment: Is you read the question, he has Web-Adapter already installed so he had to have IIS there. Sounds like he is needing to troubleshoot his network/ip configuration to get external.

Comment: OK, here is more information:

my ip 10.10.1.103

subset mask: 255.255.255.0

i put my ip address liek this "10.10.1.103/arcgis/rest, but it is not responding, in firefox says the connection has timed out, also in internet explorer,

as, i have installed IIS for arcgis server

default gateway: 10.1.1.254

Comment: any help please